# React Native : Error while updating property 'd' of a view managed by: RNSVGPath null InvalidNumber

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react native shadow for creating a custom shadow in my application, everything was working fine.

All of a sudden, its start giving the error as "Error while updating property 'd' of a view managed by RNSVGPath null InvalidNumber". After i have reinstalled all the packages using "npm i" and rebuilding the packages.

I am not using any chart based on VectorLines.

Following the example code of react-native shadow, I am using from lib.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow

Comment: Somewhere you are passing `null` as a property to a `d` svg node - probably one of the values of the `shadowOpt` object you are passing as configuration to the `BoxShadow` `setting` prop.

Comment: const shadowOpt = {
    color: "#ff3000",
    border:30,
    radius:5,
    opacity: 0.1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    style: { margintop: 5,marginBottom:25}
} this are my shadowOpt values

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause but based on the docs it seems like you must include the `height` and `width` options to match those of the child element you are wrapping in the shadow: https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow#the-attribute-we-supported-now

Comment: @azundo, i am calculating dynamic height width on the onLayout method of inner element by using its values in state variables. i.e "setting={{...shadowOpt,width:this.state.sectionCarouselElement.width,height:this.state.sectionCarouselElement.height}} "

Comment: What are the initial values before the `onLayout` callback completes?

Comment: in constructor method, i am using this this.state={
            sectionCarouselElement:{
                height:0,
                width:0
            },
        }  and inside shadow element. There is view tag, on which i am calling onLayout={(event) => this.onLayout(event)} event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all the options are in small letters on SVG, except opening and closing tags of the main SVG code tags.